# Overwrite i18next react language property type

Tags: typescript, i18next, react-i18next

We are implementing multilang in our app.
we have many functions of this shape

```
const someFunction = (lang: string, url: string) => any
```

In this case if we make mistake and will execute function like this:

```
someFunction('/some/url', 'pl')
```

Instead of

```
someFunction('pl', '/some/url')
```

We will have a problem, and typescript won't show any errors, because both of them are strings

So we decide to change function declaration to:

```
enum Language {
PL,
ENG,
ES
}

const someFunction = (lang: Language, url: string) => any
```

Now we are able to execute function this way:

```
someFunction(Language.PL, '/some/url')
```

And this is what we are looking for, however we have problem with i18next

Because WithTranslation interface has the following declaration

```
i18n: {
language: string
}
```

And useTranslation hook returns same, i18n object with language as string.

I tried many ways, however, I am too weak working with typescript and I don't know how to overwrite i18n property to has language as Language enum instead of a normal string.

If somebody knows that answer I am going to donate to some charity with a small amount of money :)
Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Please try changing your enum to a type:

```
type Language = "pl" | "eng" | "es";
```

This should work with string properties, since Language is a union of strings.

Comment: oh, is that simple? 
I willl check this after Christmas break, thanks!

Comment: unfortunately it does not work, 
When I am passing language variable from i18next what is "string" type, to the function what needs Language (one of strings) it says

"Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Language'"

Typescript probably does not know, without changing types of i18next, what is behind "language" variable from i18next.

i18next says it is just string, it does don't know that it should be limited to just few of supported in app.